# transfer mouse position from one pc to another

Tags: c++, sockets, cursor, mouse

I am trying to build a C++(clt) remote control without VNC. The screenshot stream and the keyboard control is already done and now I have no idea how to control the mouse. 
My idea is:

1. Subtract the Y position of the mouse with the postion of the form position
2. Subtract the  X position of the mouse with the left postion of the form position
3. Multiply the result with the controled pc resoultion and divide with the form  resolution (proportional)

But it doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
Remotescreenwitdh = SystemInformation::VirtualScreen.Width;                      
Remotescreenhieght = SystemInformation::VirtualScreen.Height;

double Curry = (double)(Cursor->Position.Y - this->Top);
double proportionY = (double)(screenhieght / this->Height);
double Currx = (double)(Cursor->Position.X - this->Left);
double proportionX = (double)(screenwitdh / this->Width);

int realvalx = (screenwitdh*Currx) / this->Width;                           
int realvaly = (screenhieght*Curry) / this->Height;
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it is not working?

Comment: It's calculates wrong point values and i don't get the right position in the remote pc ,it seems that something is wrong in my algorithm but it doesn't make  any sense .BTW Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Lol it's work now. I don't know how but it's started to working tnx any way.